# how to find out where garbage collector is collecting from

Tags: android, listview, garbage-collection

I have a listview in my app, and when scrolling up and down, I see in the log that the garbage collector is working quite a bit - how can i find out which operations cause it to work, and what can i do in order to avoid it? so that my list scrolling is smoother.

Comment: can you post your code? Do you have a String.format?

Answer (score 1):

Remove form your listview xml (if you don't use it) the `android:cacheColorHint`;

If it doesn't help add this lines to your xml to remove the cache of your listview:

```
android:scrollingCache="false"
android:animationCache="false"
```

Hope it helps *

Comment: I disabled them, and still no go - moreover i put a blank page on the listview item - and the garbage collector still getting called every 3 items changed- and this is the native listview widget